# How to send data from frontend to servlet without query parameters?

Tags: parameters, url-parameters, data-protection

I'm new in the world of web-development. I used to send some data via URL/query parameter to my backend (Java servlet). But now I want to change this for the sake of data protection.

```
www.domain.com/MyProject/input?member_id=12345
```

My concrete use case is to pass a member ID from the main page (with login / not created by me) to my web application and later print the member's number & name into an output file (because I want to see by whom the file is created).

What is a more secure way to pass the data, so that no one could read out the customer number easily (of course, despite of accessing the output file directly)?

Sorry for bad English, I hope I made clear what I want to achieve.

Comment: You can use Post Method ,  which is one way to protect your data from exposing in url

Comment: The credentials are not created by you, so: who creates them? The idea: the producer creates a short time valid token, the browser sends this token to you, you ask the producer if this token is valid. Just an idea. This way you can obfuscate the information you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use POST method instead of GET you are using and write member_id in the Stream.
But if security is also concerned, you encrypt member_id while sending which you decrypt at backend.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: use HTTP POST method and pass parameters within request body.

Mind out that this only hides the parameters from the URL (user can still view them if they enable browser's developer tools).